# on hover and on click how to fade out image and fade in content text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I am using a JS Fiddle idea [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4p6Lk/) to implement a css image change within a div on hover and on click.

Below is my own code in which I have implemented this, however the image that fades in is a picture of text as I do not know how to fade out an image and fade in written content. So is there any way to edit my code to fade in some content instead of fading in another image of text?

Thanks in advance.

```
   <div id="apDiv7"><div style="border-radius: 20px;" class="table-wrapper">
<div class="row row1">
    <div class="column"><img src="topright.png" width="400" height="300" class="img1" /></div>
    <div class="column"><img src="topcenter.png" width="400" height="300" class="img2" /></div>
    <div class="column"><img src="topleft.png" width="400" height="300" class="img3" /></div>
</div>
<div class="row row2">
    <div class="column"><p></p><img src="bottomleft.png" width="600" height="400" class="img4" /> </div>
    <div class="column"><p></p><img src="bottomright.png" width="600" height="400" class="img5" /></div>
</div>
</div></div>
```

css

```
.row:after {
display: block;
clear: both;
content: "";
}

.row1 .column {
width: 33.3333%;
}

.row2 .column {
width: 50%;
}

.column {
top: 20px;
float: left;
text-align: center;
}
    #apDiv7 {
position: absolute;
width: 90%;
height: 700px;
left: 5%;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-radius: 20px;
border: 8px solid #666666;
}
```

Comment: have you asked google?

Comment: @ZerO yes I have but I didnt really understand a couple of the tutorials so I was hoping somebody could spell it out for me in plain english. I am new to all this but willing to learn. :)

Comment: Question not clear.Can you explain me ...

Comment: @Shadow my apologies what is not clear?

Comment: @user3852893, am I reading this correctly that you want to have a block that starts out as an image and when it is hovered over, the image fades out and text fades in?

Comment: @user3852893  this is exactly, what I aam after :)

Comment: now i understand from @JRulle explaination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/yBK94/)**

```
<div class="hover-img">
    <img src="http://www.wholesaleforeveryone.com/content/images/blank/600/solid_color.gif" class="img1"/>
    <p class="text">place holder text goes here</p>
</div>

.hover-img {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
.hover-img > img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    z-index: 19;
}

.hover-img > p {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 9;
}

.hover-img > .img1 {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.hover-img > .text {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.hover-img:hover > .img1 {
    opacity: 0;
}

.hover-img:hover > .text {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this solution works  for you:

html

```
    <div class="hover-img">
    Text Goes Here
    </div>
```

css

```
.hover-img {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    background:url(http://www.wholesaleforeveryone.com/content/images/blank/600/solid_color.gif);
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);/*requires vendor prefix*/
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;/*requires vendor prefix*/
    line-height:200px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:0;

}
.hover-img:hover{
   -webkit-transform:rotateY(0deg);/*requires vendor*/
    font-size:14px;
    color:white;

}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/4p6Lk/9/)

Should use vendor prefixes for the all the commented props